# trouble with constants and connecting to database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm getting these errors in my on screen

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
>   Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

    private $connection;

  function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
  }

    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
```

My constants are defined as so:

```
<?php

// Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "gallery");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "phpOTL123");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Write some basic debugging code. Such as an echo inside the configuration file. That way you can see if it was actually included or not.

Comment: @mihai: it's a require. if it wasn't included, the script'd kill itself.

Comment: Set your environment to output errors instead of logging the for example `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`

Comment: @MarcB that's true enough. Unless the unlikely happens and he has multiple config files scattered around his filesystem :-).

Comment: Yeah. You always want to make sure you're editing the right file :P it must be some stupid mistake, because the code should work...

Comment: Where exactly is `php_network_getaddresses` being called. It's not present in your code.

Comment: i did set a password on the root user could that of mess things up?

Comment: thats the thing i dont have that anywhere in my code at all its just present in the errors

Comment: A password error would output a "user not allowed" message. If that's nowhere in your code then most likely it's not your code running. Do you have other applications on the same server / folder(s)? Do you have some .htaccess rules that could be going wild? Do you have include paths that could be including code incorrectly?

Comment: lesson one in debugging: put trace statements. echo, echo, echo...

Comment: I'm very sad that I didn't bother to learn how to use xdebug until about a year and a half ago. It's so much-much better than `echo` and `print_r` and `var_dump`.

Comment: take the define statements and put them in the database.php file and see what happens?

Comment: Its from an old tutorial. That my friend gave me.

Comment: Okay so I did what tom chew-head Millard said and put the constants in the database.php file and it, and it worked!. Why can I not include the config.php file as a 'require_once'?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors and a small edit fixed it. By the way you should migrate to mysqli instead of mysql.

Here is my question : [PHP constant not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522569/php-constant-not-defined)

You should replace the require_once in the database.php with the following code

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config.php");
```

It will set the path to absolute and will work smoothly and fine

Answer (score -1):

it seems that constants are not getting available to the mysql_connection function. Include the script in which constants are defined or define the constants in class **MySQLDatabase** itself.

Comment: I think he's including the script with `require_once("config.php");`

Comment: @Reda : But he doesn't mentioned it specifically in the question. Anyways thanks for devoting.