# PHP constant not defined

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working with a database project and I have created a seperate file to keep all the database information name 'config.php'. And for the database I keep another 'database.php' file in the same directory.

------------------------config.php--------------

```
<?php
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define('DB_SERVER',"localhost");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define('DB_USER',"gallery");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define('DB_PASS',"phpOTL123");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define('DB_NAME',"photomania");
?>
```

------------------------databae.php-------------

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
class MySQLDatabase{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->open_connection();
    }
    public function open_connection(){
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->conn){
            die("Database Connection Failure :(".mysql_errno());
        }else{
            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->conn,DB_NAME);
            if(!$db_select){
                die("Can't select the database".mysql_errno());
            }
        }
    }
    public function close_connection(){
        if(isset($this->conn)){
            mysqli_close($this->conn);
            unset($this->conn);
        }
    }
}

$database = new MySQLDatabase;
?>
```

---

the problem is when I include database.php in the index file using

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");
```

it gives following errors.

---

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\gallery\includes\database.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\gallery\includes\database.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\gallery\includes\database.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\gallery\includes\database.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\gallery\includes\database.php on line 11 Database
>   Connection Failure :(

---

Any help ??????

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_`

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you copy the code from `config.php` directly into `database.php`?

Comment: @Barmar Isn't OP missing `$this->conn = $conn;` in the construct, since `$conn` is private?

Comment: I don't think so. In PHP, you always access properties using `$obj->name` syntax.

Comment: Ok. Well I tested OP's code with both files in the same folder and got no problems, so it's just a path issue, far as I can tell. @Barmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you problem seems to lie in following line

```
require_once("config.php");
```

try replacing it with

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config.php");
```

Comment: Actually both files are in the same directory. Can you kindly tell me how to use this implementation in this scenario ?

Comment: It'll work with your current directory structure. `dirname(__FILE__)` returns absolute path of your current file (excluding filename)

Comment: *"the problem is when I include database.php in the index file using

require_once("../includes/database.php");"* @Ejay

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think OP is misjudging the problem :)

Comment: Hi Thank you very much it worked. But kindly can you explain me what was wrong with my previous code ?

Comment: @user3409278 You do realize that you are mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_errno()` I already stated that in [`a comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522569/php-constant-not-defined#comment36081215_23522569) in your question. They do **not** mix.

Comment: @user3409278  Do start accepting answers. You state [`in your comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343814/php-mail-scripr-confirmation#comment33966123_22344499) *"This solution worked, but I have another problem,..."* in [**your other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22343814/) but you did not click the tick/checkmark till it turns green. The question is marked as solved when doing so. Please do so for that question and this question also. That is how the SO system works and was built on and keep its ongoing success.

Comment: @user3409278 your code was fine and it would have worked fine on *nix servers. The problem is due to xampp running on windows (not exactly sure if the same is with PHP manually installed on windows). You could make it your best practice use absolute path when in doubt (or always).

Comment: user3409278 also, as @Fred-ii- has mentioned, make it your best practice to tick the answer that solves your problem. This is the least you can do to give back to the website that helped you resolve your issue.

Comment: @Ejay Oh well, you got a +1 from me. There's at least "that" ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much and extremely sorry. I am somewhat new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check if a constant is defined before defining it, you're structuring something wrong. Just remove the checks, define them, and always use require_once.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I tried that as well, but the same output. When I echo constants in the config file it works, but when it is done in databse, it fails. And when I include both config and database in the index file it works.

Comment: Then your constants are not actually defined. When you say "include" are you using `include` or `require`?

Comment: @Jessica You can see what he's using in the posted code.

Comment: Your constant are defined what the error tells you is NOTICE that the `DB_SERVER` and others will be treated as strings. Then they are found to be constants.  Change them according to my answer below this and it should work. You dont need to check if they are `defined` as you are defining them with file included by `REQUIRE`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean require_once. Yeah that's the problem, why the include in the database file doesn't work ??

Comment: @Barmar He was talking about a different file.

Comment: @Seti No, that's not what the notice is telling you. The notice says that since it couldn't find a constant named `DB_SERVER` or a variable `$DB_SERVER`, it's treating it as a typo for the literal string `'DB_SERVER'`.

Comment: @user3409278 You might try making these constants properties of the class, since you're only going to be using them in there anyway. if you switch to simply defining them, it should work, so there must be some other problem.

Comment: @Jessica The `config.php` file is probably generic, intended to be usable by different classes and non-OO code.

Comment: @Barmar really, you suspect that this particular person is trying to write such abstract code as that? Come on.

Comment: Thanks for all of your effort and help. Actually I am still learning PHP OOP. But the problem still prevails. I don't know why. Even video tutorials in the lynda.com which I refer to seems to be working on their machines. Mine works only if I add the config file to the index.php.